# convert text to snake case to camelCase in MAC OS High sierra

Tags: macos, sed, operating-system

I would like to convert 2+ words to camel case. I tried in online ubuntu version and it works. But not on mac os.

`my amazing-long_variable -> myAmazingLongVariable`

`echo "my amazing-long_variable" | sed -E 's/[ |_|-]([a-z])/\U\1/gi' | sed -E 's/^([A-Z])/\l\1/'`

My Output:

`sed: 1: "s/[ |_|-]([a-z])/\U\1/gi": bad flag in substitute command: 'i'`

2nd attempt:

`echo "my amazing-long_variable" | sed -E 's/[ |_|-]([a-z])/\U\1/g' | sed -E 's/^([A-Z])/\l\1/'`

Output:

myUamazingUlongUvariable

Thanks

Comment: Another thought - install homebrew so you have access to the GNU tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\U` and `\l` are GNU sed extensions. Perl will work for you out of the box:

```
echo "my amazing-long_variable" | perl -nE 'say lcfirst join "", map {ucfirst lc} split /[^[:alnum:]]+/'
```

You read this from right to left

- `split /[^[:alnum:]]+/` splits the default variable `$_` (i.e., the current line) on any sequence of non-alphanumeric characters, resulting in the list "my", "amazing", "long", "variable"
- `map {ucfirst lc}` applies the code `ucfirst lc` to each word in turn.

  - as you might guess, `lc` lower cases the word, then `ucfirst` capitalizes the first character
  - this results in the list "My", "Amazing", "Long", "Variable"
- `join "",` joins the words using the empty string: "MyAmazingLongVariable"
- `lcfirst` lower cases the first character: "myAmazingLongVariable"

The perl option `-n` loops over the input file and/or standard input, putting each line in the "default variable" `$_`. `-l` takes care of handling the line endings for the print command.

Comment: this is really good suggestion. How can i change it so that it finds all the file which has "my amazing-long_variable" and i replace it to camelCase using your one liner. Thanks in advance

Comment: I have files test.txt like below content:                                                              `some junk data-selenium='hello world'
some junk data-selenium='hello-world'
some junk data-selenium='hello'`       I would like to replace all `hello world` `hello-world` `hello_world` to `helloWorld`

Comment: Put the input data in your question where it can be properly formatted

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved this via below code. Not a great solution but it works ;)

```html
find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -p -i -e "s/data-selenium[\s]*=[\s]*'(\w+)[\s_-](\w+)'/data-selenium='\l\$1\u\$2'/g"
find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -p -i -e "s/data-selenium[\s]*=[\s]*'(\w+)[\s_-](\w+)[\s_-](\w+)'/data-selenium='\l\$1\u\$2\u\$3'/g"
find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -p -i -e "s/data-selenium[\s]*=[\s]*'(\w+)[\s_-](\w+)[\s_-](\w+)[\s_-](\w+)'/data-selenium='\l\$1\u\$2\u\$3\u\$4'/g"
find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -p -i -e "s/data-selenium[\s]*=[\s]*'(\w+)[\s_-](\w+)[\s_-](\w+)[\s_-](\w+)[\s_-](\w+)'/data-selenium='\l\$1\u\$2\u\$3\u\$4\u\$5'/g"
find . -name '*.java' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -p -i -e "s/data-selenium[\s]*=[\s]*'(\w+)[\s_-](\w+)[\s_-](\w+)[\s_-](\w+)[\s_-](\w+)[\s_-](\w+)'/data-selenium='\l\$1\u\$2\u\$3\u\$4\u\$5\u\$6'/g"
```